# Slurp text file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io

In Haskell, what's the most concise way to get the contents of a text file as a string given the filename? We can assume file size is not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `readFile` which has the type `FilePath -> IO String`.

```
$ echo "Hello\nMy name is ThreeFx" >> myFile.txt
$ ghci
Prelude> do { x <- readFile "myFile.txt"; print $ head $ lines x }
"Hello"
```

This should even work on large files, since `readFile` is lazy and only reads what it needs from the file.

For future reference, check [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for standard library functions. You can search by keywords or, even better, type signatures.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I managed to miss this, even tried Hoogle. Hopefully your answer will help some future Googlers. Great tip on searching type signatures!

Comment: more idiomatic would be `x <- readFile "myFile.txt", as `fmap head y` reads the file in every time.